# How can an approach to $P$ vs $NP$ based on descriptive complexity avoid being a natural proof in the sense of Raborov-Rudich?

Tags: computational-complexity, open-problems

**EDIT:** This question has been modified to make it a stand-alone question. Feel free to retract your votes for the previous version.

Here are Vinay Deolalikar's [paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Vinay_Deolalikar/Papers/pnp12pt.pdf), and Richard Lipton's first [post](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/a-proof-that-p-is-not-equal-to-np/) about it, and the [wiki](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Deolalikar%27s_P!%3DNP_paper) page on polymath site summarizing the discussions about it. His approach is based on descriptive complexity.

One of famous barriers for separating $NP$ from $P$ is Razborov-Rudich [Natural Proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_proof) barrier. Richard Lipton remarked about his paper and the natural proofs barrier that apparently "it exploits a uniform characterization of P that may not extend to give lower bounds against circuits". A question which is mentioned in one of the comments on Lipton's post is:

> How essential is the uniformity of $P$ to his proof?

i.e is the uniformity of $P$ used in such an essential way that the barrier will not apply to it? (By essential I mean that the proof does not work for the non-uniform version.)

So here is my questions:

> Are there any previous computational complexity results based on descriptive complexity that avoid the Razborov-Rudich natural proofs barrier (because of being based on descriptive complexity)?
>
> How can an approach to $P$ vs $NP$ based on descriptive complexity avoid being a natural proof in the sense of Raborov-Rudich?

A related question is:

> What are the complexity results using uniformity in an essential way other than proofs by diagonalization?

---

Related closed MO posts:
[When would you read a paper claiming to have settled a long open problem like $P$ vs. $NP$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34947/when-would-you-read-a-paper-claiming-to-have-settled-a-long-open-problem-like-p) 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34953/whats-wrong-with-this-proof-closed

Discussion on meta:
http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/590/whats-wrong-with-this-proof/

Comment: "Does his approach avoid being a 'natural proof' in the sense of Razborov and Rudich?" would be a start.  

Comment: Have you read it yourself?

Comment: Kaveh, here is my suggestion: Read the paper first and only ask a technical question if you come across a difficulty that, after thinking about it for sufficient time, you cannot overcome. Also, please, remember that, as exciting as this new development might be, MO is not a seminar on Vinay Deolalikar's paper.

Comment: I think it more polite to let experts and the usual course of events decide whether specific parts of an unpublished work is correct or not. I think that MO is a terrible place to do this, in particular because anonymous and pseudonymous comments are possible.

Comment: _interesting question!_ fyi it seems one expected major/key way to approach P=?NP question from descriptive complexity theory would be [Fagins thm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagin's_theorem) but presumably Deolalikar did not go this route... also this post by aaronson [Eight Signs A Claimed P≠NP Proof Is Wrong](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=458) has a point or two relevant to the use of descriptive complexity in a P vs NP proof & this particular proof attempt/attack.